# MySQL how to make a backup while the server is not running

Tags: mysql, backup

I made a update on my mac to catalina few days ago. After this my MySQL-Server was broken and I would like to reinstall it. Before doing this I would like to make a backup of my database. Because the server is not running I can't use mysqldump or phpMyAdmin. Is it enough to save the directory /usr/local/mysql/data/ or is there anything else I should do?

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: I think that should be enough. Try asking in [dba.se].

Comment: You MUST make a copy of ALL data directory (I'd copy `/usr/local/mysql/`). Then remove MySQL and re-install absolutely the same version. After complete try to stop daemon, replace data directory (saving created during install), and restart.